# How to modify this piece of code to be more magento2 way?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I've prepared a method to force download file its work fine but I think it's not a Magento way.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' .self::PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME . "'");
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($privateKey));
header('Connection: close');
echo $privateKey;
```

It works fine but I think it could be more magento way style. I tried:

```
$result = $this->jsonFactory->create();
$result->setHeader('Content-Disposition','filename='.self::PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_NAME . "'");
$result->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
$result->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($privateKey));
$result->setHeader('Connection', 'close');
echo $privateKey;
```

but it doesn't work as method metioned earlier. It throws fatal error. Any ideas?

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue?

Comment: No, version mentioned above commited to repo.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is because you are setting header's content-type to **"text/plain"** on **jsonFactory** ,make $result object of  `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` and it should work fine.